# in oracle data sample, Deal with Minimum salary problem per group(when duplicates exist)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

emp

```
empno   ename   job         mgr     hiredate    sal    comm   deptno
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    80/12/17    800     null   20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    81/02/20    1600    300    30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    81/02/22    1250    500    30
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    81/04/02    2975    null   20
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    81/09/28    1250    1400   30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    81/05/01    2850    null   30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    81/06/09    2450    null   10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    82/12/09    3000    null   20
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   null    81/11/17    5000    null   10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    81/09/08    1500    null   30
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788    83/01/12    1100    null   20
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698    81/12/03    950     null   30
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    81/12/03    3000    null   20
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782    82/01/23    1300    null   10
```

Each manager needs to find the employee with the smallest salary among other employees. However, the minimum annual salary is over 1000.

I tried

```
select e.ename, e.sal, e.mgr
from (select ename, sal, mgr from emp where sal > 1000) e
where (e.sal, mgr) in (select min(sal), mgr from emp group by mgr) and mgr is not null
order by sal desc;
```

and it`s result

```
ename   sal     mgr
SCOTT   3000    7566
FORD    3000    7566
CLARK   2450    7839
MILLER  1300    7782
ADAMS   1100    7788
```

As you can see, among the employees with 7698 managers, salary must be over 1000, but min is less than 1000, so it is excluded when executed with my code.

result what I want

```
ename   sal     mgr
SCOTT   3000    7566
FORD    3000    7566
CLARK   2450    7839
MILLER  1300    7782
WARD    1250    7698
MARTIN  1250    7698
ADAMS   1100    7788
```

I want the final output value to be in descending order based on salary.

What should I change in the code?

*in my oracle version -> oracle 11g

Comment: There is no `sal` column in your sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It`s corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ename, sal, mgr from emp 
where (sal, mgr) in (
  select min(case when sal >= 1000 then sal end), mgr 
  from emp group by mgr
) 
and mgr is not null
order by sal desc;
```

MIN() aggregate function can accept CASE expressions. Here, we are nullifying any values less then 1000. The MIN() will return a least NON-NULL value as long as there is at least one value that is 1000 or above for a given group.

You may also do the following, MIN() analytic function.

```
select * from (
  select emp.*, min(case when sal >= 1000 then sal end) over (partition by mgr) mn 
  from emp
)
where mgr is not null and sal = mn
order by sal desc;
```